# Different uses of the % sign in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, banner

so I'm trying to take a simple slider apart to learn from it but I'm boggled with something and can't seem to find the answer:

```
var slides = document.querySelectorAll('#slides .slide');
var currentSlide = 0;
var slideInterval = setInterval(nextSlide, 2000);

function nextSlide(){
    slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide';
    currentSlide = (currentSlide+1)%slides.length;
    slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide showing';
}
```

This is the function inside the script:

```
currentSlide = (currentSlide+1)%slides.length;
```

In this line is the % sign. I'm aware it can be used to find remainders or even utilise odd and even numbers but I can't figure out what it's doing here.

An explanation would be great.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually the same operator as mentioned in your other examples. The `%` operator is the modulus operator i.e. it returns the remainder when performing integer division.

Using `%` to find even numbers is just a specific (and very common) example as any even number divided by 2 has a remainder of 0. i.e. `even_number % 2 == 0`.

In this scenario it's being used to ensure that `currentSlide` doesn't exceed `slides.length`. For any division, the remainder ranges between 0 (when an exact multiple) and 1 less than the divisor, and then wraps around again (at the next exact multiple.) So when the last slide is reached (at index `slides.length - 1`) the next number will be an exact multiple of `slides.length` and so the remainder will be 0, taking you back to the first slide.

Answer (score 1):

`currentSlide = (currentSlide+1)%slides.length`, increments currentSlide by 1 but keeps it less than slides.length, each time currentSlide will become equal to slides.length after increment it will become 0 again because of mod(%) operation. Note that without % you will keep on increasing currentSlide and once it becomes >= slides.length, you will get undefined.